# SQL Server : list users of each database

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach

I have several databases. I want to list all the users from the database/security/users folder, User1 and User2 from here:

[image]

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT name, type_desc
FROM nameOfMyDatabase.sys.database_principals
WHERE name NOT LIKE 'public' 
  AND name NOT LIKE 'dbo'
  AND name NOT LIKE 'guest'
  AND name NOT LIKE 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
  AND name NOT LIKE 'sys'
  AND name NOT LIKE 'db%';
```

which returns the users I need, except the ones made default with the database.

Now I want a query, which does this for all the databases I have, without having to know their names, or anything about them.

I have found `sp_MSforeachdb`, but it is not recommended to use by several sites online. But if it's the only option I have, how does it work? How can I reference the current database in the SQL syntax of the query? (assuming it works like a kind of for each loop?)

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT name, type_desc
FROM ''?''.sys.database_principals
Where name not like "public" 
and name not like "dbo"
and name not like "guest"
and name not like "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"
and name not like "sys
and name not like "db%"'
```

( in this code I use ''?'' as a reference to the current database, but it returns error)
Also I would only like to run the query on dbs I created, not the generated System Databases (master, model, msdb, tempdb)

Is there another way to make this work other than sp_MSforeachdb?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'', ''model'')
BEGIN
USE [?]
SELECT name, type_desc
FROM [?].sys.database_principals
WHERE name NOT LIKE ''public'' 
  AND name NOT LIKE ''dbo''
  AND name NOT LIKE ''guest''
  AND name NOT LIKE ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA''
  AND name NOT LIKE ''sys''
  AND name NOT LIKE ''db%''
 
END'
```

`sp_MsForEachDb` is not documented so this is why it's not recommended. But if you just need it for single queries and not production code feel free to use it.

`?` is replaced by your database name, you where missing `[` and `]` around your database names.

You are also using double quotes instead of 2 single quotes. Since you use a Single quote in a string you need to escape it using a single quote.

Comment: works like a charm! any ideas, how could I exclude some dbs from this?

Comment: @KoczkaBence - Add it to the line `IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')`

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of other user created versions of `sp_msforeachdb` out there. I'm going to (shamelessly) use my own version here, which you can read more here: [A CURSOR free version of sp_msforeachdb](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/). For completeness I will include the DDL below though:

```sql
USE master;
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE [name] = N'objectlist')
    CREATE TYPE dbo.objectlist AS table ([name] sysname);
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROC sp_foreachdatabase @Command nvarchar(MAX),
                                        @Delimit_Character nchar(1) = N'?', --Character to be replaced with a delimit identified version of the datbaase name I.e. [master]
                                        @Quote_Character nchar(1) = N'&', --Character to be replaced with a single quoted (') version of the datbaase name I.e. 'master'
                                        @Skip_System bit = 0, --Omits master, msdb, tempdb and model. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Skip_User bit = 0, --Omits all user databases. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Database_List dbo.objectlist READONLY, --If @Skip_System and @Skip_User equal 1, and this is empty, an error will be thrown
                                        @Auto_Use bit = 0, --Automatically starts each command agaisnt a database with a USE
                                        @Exit_On_Error bit = 1, --If an error is occurs against a single database, the command will still be run against the remainder. Otherwise everything is rolled back
                                                                --This does not effect the @Pre_Command and @Post_Command statements
                                        @Pre_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run before @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Post_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run after @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Command_Run nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT  --Returns the generated and replaced command, for trouble shooting
AS BEGIN
 
    --Do some checking of passed values first
    --Check that @Skip_System, @Skip_User aren't both 0 or that @Database_List has some rows
    IF (@Skip_System = 1 AND @Skip_User = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List))
        THROW 62401, N'System and User databases cannot be skipped if a Database List is not supplied.', 16;
         
    IF @Delimit_Character IS NULL
        THROW 62402, N'@Delimit_Replace cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;

    IF @Quote_Character IS NULL
        THROW 62403, N'@Quoted_Replace cannot have a value of NULL.', 16; 
 
    IF @Skip_User IS NULL
        THROW 62404, N'@Skip_User cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Skip_System IS NULL
        THROW 62405, N'@Skip_System cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Auto_Use IS NULL
        PRINT N'@Auto_Use has a value of NULL. Behaviour will be as if the value is 0.';
 
    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @RC int;
 
    --Add the Pre Command to the batch
    SET @Command_Run = ISNULL(N'/* --- Pre Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Pre_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Pre Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    --Get the databases we need to deal with
    --As @Database_List might be empty and it's READONLY, and we're going to do the command in database_id order we need another variable.
    DECLARE @DBs table (database_id int,
                        database_name sysname);
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List)
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
             JOIN @Database_List DL ON d.[name] = DL.[name];
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
        WHERE (d.database_id <= 4 AND @Skip_System = 0) OR (d.database_id > 4 AND @Skip_User = 0);
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       N'/* --- Begin command for each database. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT off due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT OFF;' + @CRLF + N'DECLARE @Error nvarchar(4000);' ELSE N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' END +
                       (SELECT @CRLF + @CRLF + 
                               N'/* --- Running @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Auto_Use = 1 THEN N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name) + N';' + @CRLF + @CRLF ELSE N'' END +
                               N'BEGIN TRY' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command, @Delimit_Character, QUOTENAME(DB.database_name)),@Quote_Character, 'N' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''')) + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               'END TRY' + @CRLF +
                               N'BEGIN CATCH' + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'    SET @Error = N''The following error occured during the batch, but has been skipped:'' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + ' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'                 N''Msg '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_NUMBER()) + '', Level '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_SEVERITY()) + '', State '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_STATE()) + '', Line '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_LINE()) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +' + @CRLF + 
                                                                 N'                 ERROR_MESSAGE();' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    PRINT @Error;' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    SET @RC = ERROR_NUMBER();'
                                                            ELSE N'    THROW;'
                               END + @CRLF +
                               N'END CATCH;' + @CRLF +
                               N'/* --- Completed @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */'
                        FROM @DBs DB
                        FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)') + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                        CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT back on due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' ELSE N'' END;
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + ISNULL(@CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Post_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    EXEC sp_executesql @Command_Run, N'@RC int OUTPUT', @RC = @RC;

    SET @RC = ISNULL(@RC, 0);
    RETURN @RC;
 
END;
GO
```

You can add it as a system object if you want; i cover how in the article.

Once you have got that in, you can take your query, and put the replacement characters in as needed:

```sql
USE master;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT & AS databasename, name, type_desc' + @CRLF + --& by default injects the database's name in quotes ('') and a N prefix
           N'FROM ?.sys.database_principals' + @CRLF + --? by default injects the database's name in brackets ([])
           N'WHERE name NOT LIKE ''public''' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND name NOT LIKE ''dbo''' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND name NOT LIKE ''guest''' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND name NOT LIKE ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA''' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND name NOT LIKE ''sys''' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND name NOT LIKE ''db%'';';
DECLARE @CommandRun nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC sp_foreachdatabase @Command = @SQL, --The above SQL is the command to run
                        @Skip_system = 1, --Skips system databases
                        @Auto_Use = 1, --Automatically puts a USE at the start of each database
                        @Command_Run = @CommandRun OUTPUT; --For debugging

PRINT @CommandRun;
GO
```